# discord.py Music Bot on on_ready join a specified channel and stream a mp3 with youtube-dl

Tags: discord.py, youtube-dl

How can i play stream audio from a mp3 file with youtube-dl when the bot is ready? I already know how to connect to a channel with id but i have no idea how to play in this channel i have the YTDLSource class copied from the official basic_voice.py example and now i want to do this on on_ready
`player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True) ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)` without extensions or something.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand what you're trying to do, but you can download the video as an mp3 then using `voice_client = discord.utils.get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` ([client.voice_clients - Api docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=play#discord.Client.voice_clients)) you can get the voice client object thats in the server you're connected to. Though you will need to get the guild first since you're not doing this when someone sends a command or a message, you can do this using `bot.get_guild(#Server id you want to do this in)` and passing it as the guild parameter in the original discord.utils.get function

Then use `voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(##Mp3 File Path))` ([VoiceClient.play() - Api docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=play#discord.VoiceClient.play)) to play the mp3 file to the channel

and you can do all of this inside the on_ready function